# How do i create GIF like this for free?

Tags: images, gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make animated GIFs?](https://superuser.com/questions/22319/how-do-i-make-animated-gifs)

How do i create GIF images like this one ? Came  across some online sites but they ask to eneter set of images to make gif.

[image]

Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question but i noticed That just before Queensland is selected, the button of the first drop down box changes color repeatedly. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: I think it depeends on OS. snapshot is taken on windows 7. It doesn't change on  my system.i have XP installed.